# MongoDB Schema design for Events Management System with Full Text Search

Tags: mongodb, search, database-design, solr, connector

I'm designing a solution for Events Management System with Full Text Search functionality (preferably Solr).

Following are **4 major Entities/Document Types** in this system:

1. A **Venue** is a place where something can occur.
2. A **Title** is a description of something that can occur.
3. An **Event** is a particular title at a particular venue, starting on a particular date and ending on a particular date.
4. Within an event there will be one or more **EventTimes**, which are the individual showing/opening times within the event.

System has 2 Data sources:

1. **Daily data feeds** from 3rd party supplier.
2. **User Generated Content (UGC)** from end user of the system

I'm considering use of MongoDB as Database for this system and Solr for Full Text Search support. I'm also considering to use [Mongo Connector](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector) for keeping Data sync between MongoDB and Solr. [Mongo connector require collection in MongoDB which should directly map on Solr Document to be  populated from MongoDB](http://loutilities.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/complementing-mongodb-with-real-time-solr-search/).

In my natural design, I don't need a MongoDB collection which will hold all the attributes which needs to be searched, but due to this requirement from connector, **I'm not sure how to
create this new collection?**

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Solr is selected due to comprehensive search features Solr is offering e.g. Faceted Search, Filtering, Geospatial Search with support for multiple points per document and geo polygons, Powerful Extensions to the Lucene Query Language and many more.